# Не обновляется таблица sql при помощи pdo с использованием массивов

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Не работает  данный вариант:

```
try {
    $upd = 'UPDATE `user` JOIN `mess` ON `user`.`id_usr` = `mess`.`id_usr_ms`
    SET `mess`.`text_ms` = REPLACE(`mess`.`text_ms`, :__set_0, :__set_1)
    WHERE `user`.`login_usr` = :__login';

    $sql = $db->prepare($upd);

    $arr = Array(':__set_0' => 'text 1', ':__set_1' => 'text 2', ':__login' => 'qwerty');

    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if(is_int($val)) {
            $sql->bindParam($key, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        } else {
            $sql->bindParam($key, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }

    $sql->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    message2($e->getMessage(), 'error'); // отлавливанием ошибки
}
```

Никаких ошибок не высвечивается, но при этом таблица не обновляется.
Если же выводить не в цикле, а статично, то все выполняется с успехом и данные обновляются. Я про этот кусок кода имею ввиду:

```
$__set_0 = 'text 1'; $__set_1 = 'text 2'; $__login = 'qwerty';
$sql->bindParam(':__set_0', $__set_0, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':__set_1', $__set_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':__login', $__login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Если же просто в консоли `MySQL` данных ввести сам запрос, то все выполняется без ошибок. Еще вот такой момент, если же обновлять таблицу без использования `REPLACE();` то в любом случаи будет обновление таблицы. Не важно, с использованием массива или без массива.

В чем тут дело? Что я не написал в своем коде, чтоб вариант с массивом отработал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выкинуть всё лишнее, и сразу заработает

```
$upd = 'UPDATE user u JOIN mess m ON u.id_usr=m.id_usr_ms
       SET m.text_ms=REPLACE(m.text_ms, :set1, :set2)
       WHERE u.login_usr = :login';
$arr = array('set1' => 'text 1', 'set2' => 'text 2', 'login' => 'qwerty');
$db->prepare($upd)->execute($arr);
```

Вариант с массивом надо передавать в execute().

Comment: Работает, спасибо)